# Каким образом получить id при клике?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Есть ссылки вида:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return confirmDelete(5);">Удалить</a>
```

Где **5** - ID записи. При клике на такую ссылку вызываем функцию:

```
   function confirmDelete() {
        if (confirm("Вы подтверждаете удаление?")) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
    }
```

Вопрос: Каким образом получить внутри функции `confirmDelete` ID записи по которой кликнули?

Comment: тебе подойдет jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function confirmDelete(id) {
...
```

Хотя обычно передается `this` и работают с этим объектом. Примерно так:

```js
function confirmDelete(el) { 
  console.log(el.dataset.id);    
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return confirmDelete(this);" data-id="5">Удалить</a>
```

А еще более обычно вообще не делают встроенные в html inline обработчики.

Comment: console.log(el.dataset.id)

Comment: @MedvedevDev угу

Answer (score 1):

Через аргументы :

```js
function confirmDelete(id) {
        if (confirm("Вы подтверждаете удаление с id "+ id +" ?")) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
    }
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return confirmDelete(5);">Удалить</a>
```

А дальше можно с аяксом.